# ADFS setup and ADAL authentication

Tags: adfs

My scenario like, website and web api. when user clicks one of the menu on left side, website gets ID token from ADFS and validate in web api without showing login prompt.

Answer (score 0):

An ID token contains user information so the user first has to login somehow.

So where in your flow is the user logon?

You can use Open ID Connect Resource Owner Password for the later versions of ADFS but you still have to get the user's credentials somehow.

**Update**

You are referring to WIA - Windows Integrated Auth. The logon screen will be sent to the browser but the browser will intercept it and seamlessly sign in.

ADFS still sends the logon screen though so you have to [connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/enabling-openid-connect-with-ad-fs) from the application.

Resource Owner Password does not support WIA.

Comment: When  user opens website by default his windows login info is available. All I need get a token with user id.